# Why I don't get my real resolution of my screen?

Tags: python, pywin32

With this code, I am trying to get my screen resolution 3840 x 2160

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

And I get

```
Width = 1280
Height = 720
```

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: Only one @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: `3840/1280` gives `3.0` and `2160/720` gives `3.0` - maybe it is not metric in pixels but in something different. `dpi` ? `HDPI` ?